# What does fn-f8 do on Asus laptop?

Tags: laptop, fn-key

It has [A]/[B] printed on it, where [A] is LCD inside a box and [B] is a monitor symbol. Pressing it just turns the screen off for a second then back on.

Also, what does fn-f9 do? It looks like a square with a diagonal through it and two smaller squares inside. Pressing it does nothing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your descriptions fn-F8 would switch the output to an external monitor if one were plugged in and fn-F9 would enable/disable the trackpad.

Test it, and let me know!

Comment: I don't have another monitor to test fn-F8, but the trackpad still works after pressing fn-F9.

Comment: Is it on this picture of an asus laptop that google gave me?

http://animalcules.files.wordpress.com/2008/12/keyboard.jpg

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> then <kbd>F8</kbd> brings connects a TV via the HDMI cable.

The first time displays a laptop the second press shows a HDMI cable graphic and connects to the TV.
I have yet to get the audio to work but video is fine.